Github actions trigger Jenkins job on VPC
I have a github actions and a jenkins setup on our internal VPC.
I need to trigger specific job on this jenkins setup from the github actions.
please suggest ideas to achieve this.
One of the strategy I know is to use a public gateway for the jenkins.
